# Regex to remove all "" and []

Tags: javascript

I have a string like this:

```
const myString = "["dupa", "dupa", "dupa"]";
```

how to use regex in JS/TS to remove all characters `"` and `[` and `]`?

i need only `dupa, dupa, dupa`

thanks for any help

Comment: [`JSON.parse(myString)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: i can't because my `mystring` is an array

Comment: @masterOfDisaster it's not array it's string format. You have quotes outside the array.

Comment: @masterOfDisaster Parsing it will turn it into an array. If you want them as a string without the `[ ]` you can use the [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method after parsing

Answer (score 1):

It will return you string with other removed from it and with your double quoted there is problem with it. So use single quote.

```js
const myString = '["dupa", "dupa", "dupa"]';
const a = myString.replace(/[\[\]']+/g, '').replace(/"/g, '');
console.log(a);
```

You will get `"dupa, dupa, dupa"`

Or you can go with :

```js
const myString = '["dupa", "dupa", "dupa"]';
const a = JSON.parse(myString);
console.log(a.join(", "))
```